# PHP works in a folder but not in another

Tags: php

Ok, so I have made a form on a .html page and a .php page to upload an image and then save som data from the form along with the filepath for the image. The problem is when I move it from the root folder to root/backweb it wont work. I have created a new uploads folder in the backweb folder and also copied the conn.inc.php file over to the backweb folder for simplicity.

When I run it from the root foler it says "Releasen sparades!" (Release saved) but when I run it from the backweb server it says "Ogiltig filtyp!..." (Invalid filetype). Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<?
require_once 'conn.inc.php';

if (($_FILES["cover"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["cover"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["cover"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["cover"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
  {
  if ($_FILES["cover"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["cover"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["cover"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["cover"]["name"] . " finns redan på servern. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cover"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["cover"]["name"]);
      $cover = "uploads/" . $_FILES["cover"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Ogiltig filtyp! Endast bilder &auml;r till&aring;tna (.jpg, .png och .gif)</br>
  <a href=\"uploadform.html\">F&ouml;rs&ouml;k igen</a>";
  }


$band = $_REQUEST["band"];
$title = $_REQUEST["title"];
$catnum = $_REQUEST["catnum"];
$format = $_REQUEST["format"];

$query = "INSERT INTO releases (band,title,catnum,format,cover) VALUES ('$band','$title','$catnum','$format','$cover')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result == NULL)
    {
        echo "N&aring;got gick fel, releasen sparades ej!";
        ?>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <a href="editreleases.php">Försök igen!</a>
        <?
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Releasen sparades!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What filetype does it say it is when it's supposedly not valid?

Comment: Thats the weird thing, I upload the same file when I test it in the root and in the backweb folder. It doesn't say filetype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sound like folder permissions are not set for PHP to access files in the non-root folder

Comment: Do you think it would work if I used the same folder? Ok so what is the correct way to do so?

Like this? if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $_FILES["cover"]["name"]))

Comment: I guess you're right! I edited the code to use the other folder and the other conn.inc.php and it magically started to work!

Comment: That actually not what I meant, but if it worked - great! I had in mind apply "chmod 777" (or if you are on Windows give read permissions to everyone) to the folder and see if it make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give correct paths to your directories, ie

```
if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $_FILES["cover"]["name"]))
```

vs

```
if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["cover"]["name"]))
```

Comment: As I wrote before, I made a new upload folder inside the backweb folder for simplicity. The same code still wont work!somethings goes wrong in the first if statement.

Comment: What about `require_once '../conn.inc.php';`?

Comment: As I wrote, copied that one over too! Before that the page was blank. After I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [`is_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) instead of [`file_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)? And use `$_FILES["cover"]["tmp_name"]` for the path to the file. Example from PHP manual:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{
   echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
   echo "Displaying contents\n";
   readfile($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
}
else
{
   echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
   echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
}
```

In addition, as @trailmax notes, check that PHP can actually access the folder files are uploaded to.

Comment: You really think that I have to make this big changes to the code just cuz I move it one from root to root/backweb?

Comment: Probably not, but for example: Why would you even want to create the file path manually when you should have it right there in tmp_name? Either way, seems your problem is faulty configuration :)